# Is it appropriate to have a tag to show that a question is about the '겠' particle?

Tags: discussion

In this question:

[Why is the 겠 particle used in '알겠습니다'?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/471/why-is-the-%ea%b2%a0-particle-used-in-%ec%95%8c%ea%b2%a0%ec%8a%b5%eb%8b%88%eb%8b%a4?noredirect=1#comment758_471)

We were discussing whether `겠` itself would be a suitable tag.  it. I didn't want to tag it 'future' as '겠' doesn't have a future function here.

Is there any reason that `겠` should not, in itself, be a tag? If it shouldn't, what would be a good tag for this question? `verb-endings` seems rather non-specific, especially as '겠' is not an ending on its own - but maybe `겠` is *too* specific a tag?

Comment: I also don't know whether 겠 would be called a 'particle', 'suffix', or whatever in Korean. School me if you like!

Comment: `tenses` sounds better, but I'm not sure if they are technically tenses as they also have functions of aspects.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this dictionary definitiion for [-겟-](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=1877200), I think it is appropriate to tag it 'verb-ending (동사어미)'.

I know '-겟-' doesn't look like an ordinary verb ending, but there are too many endings in Korean. I think it would create too many tags if we tag them individually using [겟](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%ea%b2%9f).

I would like to hear other opinions.

Comment: I am trying to answer all **unanswered questions** on Meta.